# How many vectors can be in a spanning set?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I understand that for a vector space of dimension $n$, there must be at least $n$ vectors in a spanning set, but can there be more?

Comment: Perhaps you mean: for a set (vector space actually) of dimension $n$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Basically, if $V = span(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$, then every spanning set for V can there be at most $n$ vectors?

Comment: You can always add more vectors in $V$ (as long as your spanning set is not $V$ itself). And if your original set is not linearly independent, you can also have fewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean that you have a vector space, and that for a subspace of dimension $n$, any spanning set of that subspace has at least $n$ vectors in it?

This is true, and yes, there can easily be more than $n$ vectors in the spanning set. For instance, the set $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the set $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ also spans $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ linearly independent vectors  $v_1,\dots,v_n\in \mathbb{R}$ span $R_n$, i.e. $$\mathbb{R}^n=Span\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$$ any additional vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be independent to these vectors, i.e. there is $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that $$v=\alpha_1 v_1+\cdots+\alpha_n v_n,$$ therefore 
$$Span\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v\} = Span\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$$